# HP NC364T VLAN ISSUES

Tags: hp, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am having a issue with an hp quad port NIC,
I have 2 existing HP DL380 G5s with the same network card that are in a 2 node hyperv cluster.

The existing 2 servers have 2 of the 4 ports in the default vlan, 1 in vlan 30 and one in vlan 40 and the can ping their respective ip addresses. (10.0.30.10,20 and 10.0.40.10,20)

On a new dl380 g5 (was an exchange server that has now been repurposed) with an identical NC364T, it can not communicate when I plug the ports into vlan 20 or 30, it does work when connected to the default vlan.

I done nothing special on the other 2 servers, the only difference between them was I used the latest HP Support Pack as I only installed the new one today, is there something I'm missing in nic settings with the latest drivers.

Comment: vLans shouldn't be used just to reduce broadcast traffic, they should be used to separate logically distinct portions of the network, usually different types of traffic. Have you tried downloading [HPs firmware update DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1844068&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1844067&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005) and seeing what firmware and drivers are available to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the default VLAN as it is used to connect the virtual servers to the rest of the network.

How it works:

ROLE:   MGMT   |  iSCSI   |     VM Team    |Failover|Heartbeat
PORT: Onboard1 | Onboard2 | QUAD1 | QUAD 2 | QUAD 3 | QUAD 4
VLAN:    0     |    10    |   Teamed V.0   |   30   |   40

I have used untagged port based VLANs on a single switch to break the 24 ports up into smaller 4 port "switches" so that they are independent of each other to minimise broadcast traffic etc.

The onboard adapter does not have an issue with the VLAN'ing (a standard HP NC373i multifunction adapter) on the switch (A Netgear GSM7328S) nor do the 2 other servers which are configured in exactly same way, the only difference is that they have a different version of the HP Network Card Management tool, which I can not download the previous version of from HP.

I can swap the ports used by the other servers (relative to that vlan) and everything works, and if I plug QUAD3 and QUAD4 into the default VLAN they also work.

It seams very odd for this to have stopped working.

Comment: you have posted this as an Answer to your Question. This is more information for the question however, please edit it into your question. This is not a forum, only Q & A, please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on your third paragraph sorry, either way I stopped trusting 'default'/native VLANs a long time ago, they just don't always play nicely when configured how you have, why wouldn't you just state the right VLAN, it's not hard to do and clears things up nicely. Now onto your problem, have you checked the switch port configs and CAM table? What are you seeing?